# Loader is not showing during paging or filtering in MUIDatatable

Tags: reactjs, redux, mui-datatable

I am using MUIDatatable in my React project that uses redux. I am showing a loader during an api call which is working fine for the first time when MUIDatatable gets data. But when I use filter or change page from paging toolbar my loader is not showing. I use a redux setup where my reducer returns the state **loading: true** and after the api call it returns the state **loading: false** which is perfectly ok but still loader is not showing. I used the following option where I used my **loader** component:

```
const options = {
    filterType: 'dropdown',
    responsive: 'scrollFullHeight',
    serverSide: true,
    count: total,
    page: page,
    searchText: tableState.options.searchText,
    customToolbarSelect: renderCustomSelectToolbar,
    textLabels: {
        body: {
            noMatch: loading ?
                <Loader loading={loading} /> :
                'Sorry, there is no matching data to display',
        },
    }
};
```

Then I used that option into my MUIDatatable like:

```
<MUIDataTable
    title={"Service Request List"}
    data={requests}
    columns={columns}
    options={options}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution. we need to use loading props and ternary operator as below:

```
{ 
   loading ?  <Loader loading={loading}/> :
   <MUIDataTable
      title={"Service Request List"}
      data={requests}
      columns={columns}
      options={options}
   />
}
```

Answer (score 3):

options with states should be specified in the component props directly:

```
<MUIDataTable
    title={"Service Request List"}
    data={requests}
    columns={columns}
    options={{
    filterType: 'dropdown',
    responsive: 'scrollFullHeight',
    serverSide: true,
    count: total,
    page: page,
    searchText: tableState.options.searchText,
    customToolbarSelect: renderCustomSelectToolbar,
    textLabels: {
        body: {
            noMatch: loading ?
                <Loader loading={loading} /> :
                'Sorry, there is no matching data to display',
        },
    }
}}
/>
```

This will work. When options with custom states are specified in a variable, it doesn't work.

As for your solution, it does the job but "a less than desirable solution as it results in the entire table disappearing when loading new data e.g. async pagination, searching, this causes massive page jank as the table disappears and reappears every time new data is loaded"